# Is there a way to simplify multiple || logical operators in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

is there an out of box solution to simplify this:

```
if(Someresult.innerObject.AnotherObject.Property == "1"|| Someresult.innerObject.AnotherObject.Property == "4") {

}
```

This line has only two tests, if it were 6 the code would be terrible.

I would like something like this:

```
if(Someresult.innerObject.AnotherObject.Property.IsOneOf("1", "4")){
}
```

Is there a solution out of the box in C# that is similar to this?

Comment: Your title is asking about &&, your question body is asking about ||. Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,
you have to use these from the

> using System.Linq;

namespace

```
string[] stringArray = { "1", "4" };

if(stringArray.Any(Someresult.innerObject.AnotherObject.Property))
```

Comment: This does not compile. Now, if you changed `Any` to `Contains`, that would be a different kettle of fish.

Comment: also, `if(new String[] {"1", "4"}.Contains(Someresult.innerObject.AnotherObject.Property)) {.. }` is a valid option

Comment: Add this class into your project and than you can call the method you want,

static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool IsOneOf<T>(this T item, params T[] items)
    {
        if (items == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

        return items.Contains(item);
    }
}

Comment: I created an extension method... "IsOneOf" on the String class and its doing awesome. I think, it's the best option we have in C#. I am a little prejudiced about extesion methods because it seems like you chaning the framework but its not the case. It would be very tiresome if Microsoft creates methods that are too specific, the docs would be more tiresome than they already are.